# Making a self-signed SSL-certificate via FTP

Tags: ftp, ssl, sftp

My problem is, how to create a self-signed SSL-certificate by using only FTP/sFTP? Or is it even possible?

I have only FTP-connection to my client's site. I have browsed plenty of tutorials about self-signed SSL-certificates, but nothing even close to this case. Is it simply not possible to make it over FTP? Could I install cpanel etc. over FTP and make it there? I have never done any SSL-certificate before.

All I need is working SSL-certificate for my client. And no hosting company included making it. (My client doesn't want to pay for them, since they ask rather much.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible to create a certificate via FTP, but there is a solution
to your client's unwillingness to pay for one. How about a free certificate?

[Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)
is a free, automated, and open Certificate Authority recognized world-wide.
You may create the certificate via the
[SSL For Free](https://www.sslforfree.com/) website.

Another well-known furnisher of free SSL certificates is
[Cloudflare Free SSL/TLS](https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/).
See 
[this page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/signin?return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.cloudflare.com%2Fhc%2Fen-us%2Farticles%2F200170516-How-do-I-add-SSL-to-my-site-)
for further instructions on setting up SSL with Cloudflare.

Free certificates can also be created via the
[Comodo SSL Free Trial](https://ssl.comodo.com/free-ssl-certificate),
limited to one issuance per domain.

Comment: But how do I install a free certificate only with FTP?? No cpanel, no nothing...  Hosting company is not willing to offer any support, but only their own certificate services. Could it help that there is WordPress? Could I have some plugin there to help?

Comment: It's impossible to use FTP as a shell. You should ask for SSH access to the computer, then you could run programs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answers, harrymc! I think this case is now closed. I'll tell my client that they need to pay what the hosting company asks for a certificate. Have a nice day!

Comment: If my answer has helped with the problem, please accept it (tick the V sign).

Comment: ...By the way, how to mark this question as solved? Somehow I can't find it...

Comment: There a V sign to the left of the answer. Just click on it.